# How do I assign a delegate extension method in c#?

Tags: c#, delegates, extension-methods

I want to get all the dates between two endpoints using a provided frequency. So I'm basing my approach off this simple bit of code:

```
for (DateTime date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
            datesBetween.Add(date);
```

Now, I sometimes have a need to add days (as above), add months, or add years based on a `FrequencyEnum`

So I could use a `switch` and repeat the code 3 times for my uses, but I'm wondering if I can assign a delegate extension method rather than `.AddDays` or `.AddMonths` or `.AddYears`

Rather, I'd like to do something like this:

```
for (DateTime date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = date.AddFrequency)
            datesBetween.Add(date);
```

where `.AddFrequency` is delegate defining the extension method needed for my frequency.

Alternatively, I could **not** use an extension method and simply use a function taking a date parameter and return as needed.

Comment: Whats wrong with  `var freq = Frequency.Year;` `...` `date = date.AddFrequency(freq)` ?

Comment: @leppie nothing, that would probably work too but assigning my specific frequencyEnum in an extention method to DateTime seems wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a `Func<DateTime, DateTime>`

```
Func<DateTime, DateTime> updater = d => d.AddFrequency(Frequency.Month);

for (DateTime date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = updater(date))
     datesBetween.Add(date);
```

Of course, in your real code, your method would likely accept the delegate as an argument rather than initialize it on its own.

That said, with [moreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/), you could just do:

```
var datesBetween = startDate.Generate(date => date.AddDays(1))
                            .TakeWhile(date => date <= endDate);
```

Comment: I like this solution, it basically offloads my `Switch` to another method and keeps me from having to repeat the `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that. Extension methods must be static methods inside a static class.

But you could write an `AddFrequency` extension method that takes a frequency and a count. So you could write:

```
date = date.AddFrequency(FrequencyEnum.Months, 3)
```